# A variation of the dual group of the adjoint group

Tags: algebraic-groups, reductive-groups

Let $\mathbf{G}$ be connected reductive group over a $p$-adic field $F$. Denote by $\mathbf{Z}$ the center of $\mathbf{G}$, and $\mathbf{A}$ the maximal split torus of $\mathbf{Z}$ (also called the split component). Let $\hat{G}$ be its dual group, i.e. the connected reductive complex Lie group with the root datum dual to the absolute root datum of $\mathbf{G}$.

I know the following fact: the dual group of the adjoint group $\mathbf{G}_{\mathrm{ad}}:=\mathbf{G}/\mathbf{Z}$ is the **simply connected cover** of the derived subgroup $\hat{G}_{\mathrm{der}}$. For example, if $\mathbf{G}=\mathrm{Sp}(2n)$, then $\hat{G}=\mathrm{SO}(2n+1,\mathbb{C})$. The center $\mathbf{Z}=\{\pm I\}$, and the dual group of $\mathbf{G}_{\mathrm{ad}}:=\mathbf{G}/\mathbf{Z}=\mathrm{PSp}(2n)$ is indeed the spin group $\mathrm{Spin}(2n+1,\mathbb{C})$.

My question is: I think the dual group of $\mathbf{G}/\mathbf{A}$ should be a subgroup of $\hat{G}$ containing $\hat{G}_{\mathrm{der}}$, is this right?  Roughly speaking, I think the finite fold cover should come from the connected components of the anisotropic part of $\mathbf{Z}$. ($\mathbf{Z}$ may not be connected, while $\mathbf{A}$ is connected.) But I'm not quite sure whether this statement is true in general.

Any help/suggestion is welcome. Thanks in advance (and happy new year)!

Comment: Yes, I think so.
You have surjective homomorphisms
$$ {\bf G}\to {\bf G}':={\bf G}/{\bf A}\quad\ \text{and}\quad\ {\bf G}'\to {\bf G}_{\rm ad}\,, $$
whence by duality you obtain injective homomorphisms 
$$ (\hat G)_{\rm der}\to \widehat{G'}\quad\ \text{and}\quad\  \widehat{G'}\to \hat G.$$